# Question Mark in URL not encoded properly

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, url

I am trying to make a URL pattern like below on button click of angular typescript application:

http://localhost:4200/SamplePage/scheduler?UsecaseId=3

[image]

Where usecase.UsecaseId is a numeric value.

```
<td>
  <button class="btn, btn-prmary btm-sm" type="button" (click)="redirectToChildPage('/SamplePage/scheduler?UsecaseId=usecase.UsecaseID')">
  <i class="fa fa-calender"></i></button> &nbsp;Schedule
</td>
```

But,I am getting this URL pattern (actual)

http://localhost:4200/SamplePage/scheduler%3FUsecaseId%3Dusecase.UsecaseId

[image]

How i can properly encode the URL as below:(expected)
[image]

**redirectToChildPage**

```
redirectToChildPage(url) {
        this.router.navigate([url]);
    }
```

Comment: can you show me your redirectToChildPage function

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
redirectToChildPage(yourvalue) {
    this.router.navigate(['url'], { queryParams: { query: yourvalue } });
  }
```

you need to add query params in your function to work it properly!

for more details, you can check [here](https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/)!

**Solution**

```
<td> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" (click)="redirectToChildPage('/his/scheduler',usecase.UsecaseId)"> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button> &nbsp;Schedule </td>
```

> ```
>  this.router.navigate([url], { queryParams: { UsecaseId: usercaseID } });
> ```

Comment: <td>
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button"
                                                 (click)="redirectToChildPage('/his/scheduler',usecase.UsecaseId)">
                                                 <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button> &nbsp;Schedule
                                            </td>

Comment: this.router.navigate([url], { queryParams: { UsecaseId: usercaseID } });

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [encodeURI](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp) and [decodeURI](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp) they can help you.

Comment: This actually belongs to the comments section.

Comment: I tried (click)="redirectToChildPage(encodeURI('/SamplePage/scheduler?UsecaseId=usecase.UsecaseId')">  but the page broke :(